# Node.js not serving files other than index.html

Tags: node.js, express, server

I'm really lost. I have been searching around for an hour now and nothing I find seems to work. Not when I put the public files in a separate folder and do things that way.

[image]

Comment: Remove the hardcoded `index.html` in the handler for the `/` endpoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to serve statics files according to this link http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html .

So in your zombie_dice you can create a "public" folder, put your css and js files in this new folder and add `app.use( express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))` in your app.js

Comment: This solved the problem. Now I can't get socket.io/socket.io.js.

http://imgur.com/V2G1k96

Comment: the socket.io package is in node_modules/socket.io ... so you can create another static file handler with an alias like this `app.use("/socket",express.static(path.join(__dirname,'node_modules','socket.io')));` and call it in your html with `/socket/socket.io.js`

Comment: Never mind I solved the problem. Thanks for your help! :)